# Why suggestion list not getting populated for suggestion box in gwt.?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, suggestbox

I am working with suggestion box in GWT but I stuck with a problem in which suggestionBox.showSuggestionList() not showing any results through focusHandler.

I have created a suggestion oracle and suggestBox as follows

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle mySuggestionOracle=new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
SuggestBox mySuggestBox=new SuggestBox(mySuggestionOracle);
```

then after when I got suggestionList values i.e. array of suggestions from somewhere I add those values to suggestion oracle like

```
for(String str : suggestionList){
    mySuggestionOracle.add(str);
}
```

Above code is written in view and I add FocusFandler to this suggestBox in presenter as,

```
view.mySuggestBox().getValueBox().addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
            view.mySuggestBox().setText(" ");
            view.mySuggestBox().showSuggestionList();
        }
    });
```

what can be issue, why this showSuggestionList() doesn't show any suggestions if we click in suggestBox.? but if we enter some text in suggestBox then it shows proper suggestions specific to input. i.e. if we enter a it shows all suggestions starts with a*.

Can someone help if had same scenario or some idea if I am wrong somewhere.?

Answer (score 2):

First, to show default suggestions, you must **set blank string as text** in the **SuggestBox** before to call showSuggestionList method ( I suppose no string in suggestionList begins whith white space).

```
public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {   
  view.mySuggestBox().setText("");  
  view.mySuggestBox().showSuggestionList(); 
}
```

Seconds, to display all suggestions, you must set them with **setDefaultSuggestionsFromText** method of **MultiWordSuggestOracle** object.

Example of constants

```
final static String[] SUGGESTIONS = {"alfred", "alicia", "bernard", "bruno", "bernadette"};
final static List<String> suggestionList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SUGGESTIONS));
```

Your initialization code :

```
for (String str : suggestionList) {
  mySuggestionOracle.add(str);
}
mySuggestionOracle.setDefaultSuggestionsFromText(suggestionList);


mySuggestBox = new SuggestBox(mySuggestionOracle);
mySuggestBox.setLimit(suggestionList.size());
```

Comment: and what if I create my custom oracle which will takes value from database through async call inside my oracle class.?